# How do I only return TRUE for full word matches in my doctest?

Tags: python, doctest

I've got a doctest to return `TRUE` if a species name starts with `quercus` but it also returns `TRUE` if the given species name contains a typo (e.g. `quercuss`). How do I make sure that `TRUE` is returned not only if it starts with that species name and matches the full word only?

```
def is_an_oak(name):
    """ Returns True if name is starts with 'quercus'""" 
    return name.lower().startswith('quercus')
```

I tried leaving a space after the word but it omitted the results when using the function further into my script:

```
def is_an_oak(name):
    """ Returns True if name is starts with 'quercus'""" 
    return name.lower().startswith('quercus ')
```

Comment: Could you give some examples of `name` that don't work with either version, and the expected results? What do you mean by "omitted results" - was something detected as not an oak that should be an oak?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
def is_an_oak(name):
    """ Returns True if first word in name is 'quercus'""" 
    return name.split()[0].lower() == 'quercus'
```

Edit considering OPs comment:
What I've added is splitting the string by spaces (`.split()`) then taking the first word (`[0]`) and doing the comparison on it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but I should have been more explicit. The test should take any full species name (E.g. 'Quercus robur' or 'Francinus excelsior' and return TRUE if the first word matches 'quercus' only.

Comment: oh i see, if only the first full word needs to match ill edit my answer with that case in a minute

Comment: Hi Toni, this did the trick perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad i could help :D

Answer (score 1):

For getting the word;

```
import re

def is_an_oak(name):
    """ Returns Name if name is 'quercus'""" 
    return re.match("^[qQ]uercus*",name).string
```

For getting TRUE/FALSE

```
 import re

 def is_an_oak(name):
     """ Returns True if name is 'quercus'""" 
     if re.match("^[qQ]uercus*",name):
         return True
     else:
         return False
```

Comment: Thanks to you to for your help. I went with another option but I will try using regular expressions next time I have a similar problem. Have a great weekend!